# Openshift successfully download and collect but fails to build

Tags: python, openshift

I tried to start an application in openshift of this repository that still works locally.

I chose to package it with Python and not with Django + PostreSQL because I did not use Django to develop my application that uses Flask elsewhere (and my life as well).

```
Status: Failed,
```

But I can not find the error from the log:

```
Log from Jun 13, 2018 5:36:32 PM to Jun 13, 2018 5:41:59  PM:
Cloning "https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot " ...
    Commit: 8097e1fa24416fcad4ee480ff67042e84e21f8fe (added the test file)
    Author: Your Name <antoine.coppin@dauphine.eu>
    Date:   Sat Jun 9 15:13:24 2018 +0100
Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/python-35-rhel7@sha256:475605d0be481c376fb52decc18c490122ddddb1fcaa81a1eabb40b735068500" ...
---> Installing application source ...
---> Installing dependencies ...
Collecting git+https://github.com/apixu/apixu-python.git  (from -r requirements.txt (line 36))
Cloning https://github.com/apixu/apixu-python.git  to /tmp/pip-dh1nybxt-build
Collecting gevent==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/dd/17dc7e899ac7c1de2d19b367b29d90fdb4cfe83bda8c2581464906c9399d/gevent-1.2.1.tar.gz  (2.8MB)
Collecting Klein==17.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/3d/9b3cc6913cf95b40af1972222c757927f26a442b3fd0e6cc652d2a622d94/klein-17.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Collecting boto3==1.4.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/60/649da03299624f524c8d0cd4c6c73c194023e85dd4938f1e7712ab6888bf/boto3-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl  (127kB)
Collecting typing==3.5.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/0c/53c42edca789378b8c05a5496e689f44e5dd82bc6861d1ae5a926ee51b84/typing-3.5.3.0.tar.gz  (60kB)
Collecting future==0.16.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/2b/8d082ddfed935f3608cc61140df6dcbf0edea1bc3ab52fb6c29ae3e81e85/future-0.16.0.tar.gz  (824kB)
Collecting six==1.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/0a/b6723e1bc4c516cb687841499455a8505b44607ab535be01091c0f24f079/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Collecting jsonschema==2.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/de/47e35a97b2b05c2fadbec67d44cfcdcd09b8086951b331d82de90d2912da/jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Collecting matplotlib==1.5.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/4e/2374eed18ac34421ccd7b4907080abd3009e112ca2c11b100c18961312e0/matplotlib-1.5.3.tar.gz  (51.6MB)
Collecting requests==2.14.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/b0/286e8a936158e5cc5791d5fa3bc4b1d5a7e1ff4e5b3f3766b63d8e97708a/requests-2.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  (560kB)
Collecting tqdm==4.11.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/0d/174388e99e21ee2c91ea318994c3f8744e26158e43cff0ec9d045bf08a96/tqdm-4.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  (46kB)
Collecting numpy==1.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/3a/40967d9f5675fbb097ffec170f59c2ba19fc96373e73ad47c2cae9a30aed/numpy-1.13.1.zip  (5.0MB)
Collecting simplejson==3.11.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/48/c97b668d6da7d7bebe7ea1817a6f76394b0ec959cb04214ca833c34359df/simplejson-3.11.1.tar.gz  (78kB)
Collecting spacy==1.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/aa/755943184fbde85b77f52f1f9f52621fdcdda67f74db4f60880e3468ee8b/spacy-1.8.2.tar.gz  (3.3MB)
Collecting scikit-learn==0.19.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/2c/5edf2488897cad4fb8c4ace86369833552615bf264460ae4ef6e1f258982/scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz  (9.5MB)
Collecting sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/9a/e045ac8cdfc33d5972474ab2108662652098e63c08b657f32cbd53f77cee/sklearn_crfsuite-0.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Collecting apscheduler==3.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/ff/eb9d27536f25253c09573cc7afc6db9708ea0abad02f5ac031b412d5cbda/APScheduler-3.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl  (56kB)
Collecting fakeredis==0.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/02/164f5f34198ebd3418665ce17d70b33dae38f58c0b121ba37502ad4a33f4/fakeredis-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Collecting graphviz==0.7.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/65/0460bcb4957e027ad31d351af170dd1759aee68c90ca598ee930ac115dd1/graphviz-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Collecting h5py==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/6b/32cee6f59e7a03ab7c60bb250caff63e2d20c33ebca47cf8c28f6a2d085c/h5py-2.7.0.tar.gz (256kB)
```

Is it a memory error?

Comment: Since the log shows it failing during dependency downloads, I think it's safe to say that it's memory related. Try increasing build memory limit to allow if to build all the way to completion.

Comment: Installation of numpy from source code will result in memory blowing out. As Will says, increase amount of memory dedicated to the build. You can find details of how to do it in the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Comment: Actually, easier link with details is http://cookbook.openshift.org/building-and-deploying-from-source/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-of-memory-a-build-can-use.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thank you, I'm installing the Server on my desktop then. I just got an error message with Kubernetes which I talk about in [this question on Kubletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992015/should-i-install-kubelet-for-openshift).