# Should I install Kubelet for OpenShift?

Tags: docker, openshift-origin, kubelet

I'm trying to download the OpenShift Origin server with [this tutorial](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#downloading-the-binary) in order to be able to increase amount of memory dedicated to the build. Yet Whil following the tutorial I tried to launch the server but got an error about Kubelet. I have Ubuntu 16.04.

```
~/openshift-origin-server-v3.9.0-191fece-linux-64bit$ sudo ./openshift start
....
F0622 17:00:24.659470   14610 server.go:173] failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: failed to get docker version: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Should I install it ? I don't think it was written in the tutorial.
Sorry if that sounds dumb, I'm new to web deployment.

Comment: Try to see if your docker daemon is running

Comment: Usually you would use RHEL, CentOS or Fedora, not sure if Ubuntu can be used. Why not just use ``oc cluster up`` or Minishift?

Comment: You can increase amount of memory for a build by following instructions in http://cookbook.openshift.org/building-and-deploying-from-source/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-of-memory-a-build-can-use.html you don't need a special OpenShift setup, it should work with any so long as you aren't trying to increase it beyond any quota which might be getting applied.